# English for "ayudante de cátedra"

Tags: translation, spanish

I have to translate "ayudante de cátedra" from a Spanish document. This is a university job that a former good student of a course can take. The student's job is to answer questions from the current students of the course, do extra exercise solving sessions and help the professor with the test revisions.
I'm not sure if "professor assistant" is the right translation.
What do you think?

Comment: TA or teaching assistant is common for this in the US

Comment: "Assistant professor" (or "teaching assistant", if lesser qualification is required).

Comment: Please feel free to post your answers as answers. That way we can vote for the best.

Comment: Possible related: *[Term for a person who conducts practice lessons](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/)*

Answer (score 1):

Teacher's assistant in the US.  Not sure what the equivalent would be in the UK.

Comment: A *Teacher's Assistant* is an assistant to a primary or secondary teacher; it's a permanent job. A _Teaching Assistant/TA_ (or _Graduate Student Instructor/GSI_ at some schools), by contrast, is a temporary job taken by a graduate student to earn money, pay tuition, and gain experience as a teacher of the discipline they're studying. One or more TAs get assigned to most large classes in big universities; that's one reason there are so many English grad students -- they teach freshman comp.